# Soft Deleted Data but issue while fetching | EF Core, C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, soft-delete

I have an issue, I have 2 tables. as below.

```cs
public class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string CampaignTitle { get; set; }
    public string CampaignObjective { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
}

public class Currency
{
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyTitle { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
}
```

I am using GlobalQuery Filters to filter out Soft Deleted data.

```cs
entityConfiguration.HasQueryFilter(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
```

I am using the below query

```cs
return await _context.Campaigns.Include(x => x.Currency).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**What is the best approach to the above query, to fetch related data ( which is deleted and required as well; in this case currency )**

For End-user data is deleted, if i fetch and show, it will confuse user, if i do not fetch and pass Campaign.CurrencyId=null then model level error ( CurrencyId != null )

Any help will be appreciated, I have searched but could not find a solution or a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some kind of solution with `IgnoreQueryFilters` like:

```cs
return await _context.Campaigns.IgnoreQueryFilters().Include(x => x.Currency).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: But seems only to work with Entity Framework Core 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 5.0
(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.ignorequeryfilters?view=efcore-5.0)

Otherwise try this: https://entityframework-dynamicfilters.net/overview